# Can we dynamically reference a field name in a Formula Field using Hierarchy Custom Setting?

Tags: formula, error, customsetting

I'm trying to build a Formula Field (Number type) like this:

```
TODAY() - DATEVALUE( $Setup.Global_Options__c.Custom_Field_Name__c )
```

And in the Custom Setting I'm setting value of the field `Custom_Field_Name__c` with value `CreatedDate` or an Admin can also change this value themselves.

But the Formula output is always returning `#Error!` as value.

Though there are no compilation errors, so I was thinking may be I'm using the Hierarchy Custom Setting value incorrectly in formula. Can someone suggest a correction?

Comment: If they can change the hierarchy setting, they can change the formula...

Comment: sry I didn't understood your comment above. But yes, they can change custom setting, though the field is supposed to be locked in a managed package. The idea is to allow user pick a field for evaluation in the Formula Field's formula.

Comment: No, you can't do what you want in this way.

Comment: This formula, as written, tries to subtract the value stored in Custom_Field_Name__c after converting it to a date. So, for example, you can write in "2017-08-30" and it would output 0 (for today's comment). As Adrian said, you can't dynamically choose fields in the formula.